# How to recognize "is typing..." in Quickblox chat?

Tags: quickblox

In a chat 1:1 (being it the native QB chat 1:1 feature or a Chat room for 2 users), how can I let a user know that his opponent is typing? Is it even posible with Quickblox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. It's called Chat State Notifications

Here is a guide how to do this in 1-1 Chat

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Chat_State_Notifications

Comment: How can we implement this for room chat? We cannot send custom parameters in room chat, right?

Comment: You can send for example json as a message body and parse it or something like that. Just use message as a transport to any data

Answer (score 1):

> Swift 4.2 :

When `userA` is typing we can send typing Notification to `userB` using `sendUserIsTyping()` method of `QBChatDialog` class.

```
private var dialog: QBChatDialog!

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        // send typing notification to opponent user here
        self.dialog.sendUserIsTyping()
    }

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        // stop typing notification when user finish his typing
        self.dialog.sendUserStoppedTyping()
    }
```

Receive typing notification when opponent user is starts and stops typing

**One To One Chat :**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    // this will get called when opponent user is starts typing
    self.dialog.onUserIsTyping = {(userID: UInt) in
       print("Typing Starts")
    }

    // this will get called when opponent user is stops typing
    self.dialog.onUserStoppedTyping = {(userID: UInt) in
        print("Typing Stopped")
    }

    }
```

---

**Group Chat :**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    self.dialog.onUserIsTyping = {(userID: UInt) in
        if self.dialog.type == .group {
            // fetch username or login name from userID
            QBRequest.user(withID: userID, successBlock: { (res, user) in
             // check sender user id and receiver user id should not same
                if self.senderID != userID {
                    if let name = user.fullName {
                        print("\(name) is typing...")
                    } else if let login = user.login {
                        print("\(login) is typing...")
                    }
                }
            }) { (response) in  }
        } else if self.dialog.type == .private {
         print("Typing Starts...")
        }
     }



    self.dialog.onUserStoppedTyping = {(userID: UInt) in
         if self.dialog.type == .group {
            //No one is typing
         } else if self.dialog.type == .private {
            print("Typing Stopped")
        }
    }

  }
```